# Way to get vertex index to use in new vertex group from selected faces

Tags: python, vertex-groups, bmesh

I try and not undertand if i am on the right way, that code i want to set the select
faces, make a vertex group, this is a piece of code:

```
    ob = bpy.context.object
    me = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)


    vertex = [v for v in bm.verts if (v.select==True and not v.hide)]       
    ver_grp = ob.vertex_groups.new(name = "My vertex group")

    ver_grp.add(???,0,'Replace')###not sure if replace can make ex novo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the way

Let's talk about the **vertex list line** first

You can use `v.index` for list: `vertex = [v.index for v in bm.verts if (v.select==True and not v.hide)]`, so the vertex will be a list contains your vertices indices.

Next, `vertex_group.add()` method:

It need 3 arguments `(index, weight, type)`:

- `index`: should be a list contain indices
- `weight`: should be a float value in 0.0~1.0
- `type`: should be a string in `{'REPLACE', 'ADD', 'SUBTRACT'}`

So you can use `ver_grp.add(vertex,1.0,'REPLACE')` for it

Sum up your code:

```py
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') #You need to enter edit mode for bmesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# not a good practice to use vertex for vertices indices list
v_indices = [v.index for v in bm.verts if (v.select==True and not v.hide)]      
ver_grp = ob.vertex_groups.new(name = "My vertex group")

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') #You need to enter object mode for add()
# Add . in float number help people know it is a float instead of int
ver_grp.add(v_indices, 1.0, 'REPLACE') # most of the blender string enums use upper case
```

Comment: Ty , work , in my script  this is performed by a button that appears only in edit mode, is there a way not to exit edit mode for apply ?

Comment: @Andrea I don't know, I always set the mode. You can swap back your mode by `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` or `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()` in the end of this script. Operator should stay in place while the `@poll()` still work

Comment: Can you explain why you added this comment line please? # not a good practice to use vertex for vertices indices list

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook I was pointing out the original variable name `vertex`, which is actually a list of vertex.  Should always name for it's plural form to make code less confusing. This is useful when code is long enough and you cannot find the definition of the variable at the first glance. `vertex_list` or `vertices` or anything else will better describe the list.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I would agree with that. Otherwise one could get very confused.